# Xamarin error on visual studio

Tags: xamarin

I install xamarin on my visual studio and when i want to create a blank app project it gives error :Object refrence not set to an instance of an object.

this is out put:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iym0p.png)

Comment: I suggest you to elaborate your question. You barely explained the error and did not ask anything.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't install the (right) Android SDKs.

Go into *Tools* > *Options* and find the 'Xamarin' page. Then go into 'Android Settings' and check if the SDK path is found.

[image: Android settings page]

If these aren't filled correctly you should install them. Easiest is to [download the installer](https://www.xamarin.com/download) from Xamarin or reinstall from Visual Studio (through add/remove applications and edit Visual Studio installation).

You can install and manage seperate SDKs by using the Android SDK manager. You can find this under *Tools* > *Android* > *Android SDK manager*.

[image: Android SDK manager menu]

In the next screen you can install the SDKs you want to use with the according emulator images, etc.